# Разработка под Android в Windows vs Linux

Tags: android, linux, windows, android-sdk, android-studio

Стал вопрос смены ОС. Два варианта:

1. Windows
2. Linux

Последний год работал только под виндой. Но не хочу ставить всякие сборки и тд, а оригинального образа Windows 7 нигде не могу скачать(вопрос о покупке лицензии не стоит). По сему смотрю в сторону Linux.

**На сколько проблематичней разрабатывать под Андроид в Линухе ?**

Comment: Образ десятки можно свободно у мелкомягких скачать и себе поставить. Висит просто надпись "Активируйте" и всё)

Comment: А вообще ща тут холивар начнётся) Моё ИМХО - ну его, это ваш линукс)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, 10 мне как-то кажется какой-то дикостью и где-то читал, что были проблемы с Андроид Студией в ней. Вы под 10 работаете ?

Comment: Никаих проблем с релизной (v.1.5) версией Android Studio под Windows 10 нет :)

Comment: @pavlofff, это хорошо, спасибо) но тут еще есть проблема, что не все драйвера есть под вин 10 для моего ноута..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить о Ubuntu (Kubuntu - с оболочкой KDE), то особых проблем не предвидится. ОС имеет свою специфику для человека неподготовленного, однако времена консольных команд и красных глаз давно прошли, 99% действий -GUI.  Любые гайды в инете присутствуют в полном объеме.
Именно разработка никаких существеных отличий не имеет - та же Android Studio, в общем то никаких проблем не ожидается - IDE обеспечивает полный цикл разработки и особых отличий по ОС не имеет.

Отдельно замечу по сопутствующему софту - лично мне Gimp и Inkscape во много милее всяких Photoshop-ов.

В общем, если саму ОС видишь в первый раз, то требуется небольшое количество времени на вхождение - иная структура каталогов и полномочий, инсталяция софта (по мне, система репозиториев во много перспективнее и удобнее хаоса устроенного Windows).. да в общем то и все.
Конкретно работа приложений не имеет каких-то существенных отличий, та же оконная концепция с управление мышью, особенно при использовании KDE в качестве оболочки - о том, что это не винда и не думаешь.

Насчет дистрибутива - их множество. Однако на сегодняшний день предпочтительнее что то, работающее с пакетами формата .deb (debian/ubuntu в основе, так как собрать пакет этого формата считает своим долгом практически любой, кто разррабатывпет софт под Linux). Разумным компромисным выбором будет Linux Mint, та же Ubuntu, но с предустановленными проприетарными состоставляющими - коммерческие драйвера, кодеки и тп. Философия оригинальной Ubuntu не позволяет все это включить в дистрибутив, так как она - чистый Open Source (но все в принципе доустанавливается после инсталяции ОС).

Отдельным бонусом идет эстетическое удовольствие - KDE очень визуально красива, Gnome приятно лаконичен - под обоих тем оформления миллиарды, тот же Compiz ([3D-менеджер композиции интерфеса](http://youtube.com/watch?v=B-FVJoZ-zwI)) сам по себе "всасывает" - и вот ты уже вместо работы целый день настраивал, как окошки перекатываются, не потому, что сложно, а потому, что вариантов офомления множество и один лучше другого :).

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! В целом для меня Linux не дикость, но Windows роднее, я за ней больше времени провел. На счет PS и других таких программ, я боюсь, что не найду удобную и настолько мощную замену в Linux'е. А на счет всяких плюшек, так это да, там много всего такого. Помню conky - "вместо работы целый день настраивал" :)

Comment: Вы разрабатываете под Андроид в Линуксе ?

Comment: @researcher Нет, у меня сейчас основная ОС Windows 10. Раньше основной была Kubuntu, но в силу давления обстоятельств пришлось пару лет назад отказаться, а андроид-разработкой я несколько позже начал интересоваться. С IDEA работал под Linux в части Java-разработки, никаких особых проблем не припомню - воспоминания остались сугубо положительные.

Comment: У вас были какие-то проблемы с 10 по сравнению с 7 ? Какие-то программы не ставились или драйверов не было?

Comment: @researcher Нет, вообще никаких проблем не было. Из того софта, что я пользуюсь все продолжило работать (было обновление с 8 на 10). Драйвера тоже проблем не доставляли (работают все от 8-ки, если нет под 10) хотя и особо специфичных устройств у меня нет.

Comment: окей) буду пробовать! спасибо!